# JavaScript email validation - String variable before the @

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation, email

I need to validate an email address input in JavaScript. The format should be name@xx.xx where "name" is another input text in the form and I have it in a var called "name_input".

I don't know how to be sure that the email will contains that variable before the `@` sign.

Comment: "I don´t know how to be sure that the email will contains that variable before the @" - Do you need to know if the `name_input` variable is not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex for this. Just `String#indexOf` will be suffice:

```
var email = 'name@xx.xx';
var name_input = 'name';

var isValid = (email.indexOf(name_input + '@')  == 0);
//=> true
```